# Webpart - Get user ID of user profile

Tags: development, web-part

I am going to create a webpart located in user profile page. That webpart should get the user ID of user's profile. For example, I login as user A and access to profile of user B, the webpart located on user B profile should get user ID of user B.

Please help me for the coding.

Answer (score 0):

A relativley simple solutions would be:

creating a workflow using the "extract substring from index of string" action and add a lookup to the action. Use the following parameters:
Data Source: Current Item
Created By: Created By
Return Field as: Display Name

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for, I hope it helps.

Comment: Seems like a very strange way for getting a user name in a webpart?